# Cannot get relation in Laravel pivot tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to build relations between three tables in laravel. Currently i have three models

**Classroom**,

```
public function subjects(){
return $this->belongstoMany('Subject','subject_section_classroom');
}
```

**Section**,
**Subject**

My Tables are

```
classrooms(id, name)
sections(id, name)
subjects(id, name)
subject_section_classroom( id, classroom_id, section_id, subject_id)
```

In my classroomsController I have

```
public function assignsubjects($class_id, $section_id){
        $classroom = Classroom::find($class_id);
        $section = Section::find($section_id); 
        $subjects = Subject::lists('name','id'); 
        $selected_subjects = $classroom->subjects()->where('section_id', '=', 1);
        $subjects = Subject::lists('name','id'); 
        return view('assignedit', compact('classroom','section','subjects', 'selected_subjects')); 
}
```

But I can't get the selected_subjects from above relation. And when I tried to get the sql of the above query (with ->toSQL()), I get

```
`"select * from `myschool_subjects` inner join `myschool_subject_section_classroom` on `myschool_subjects`.`id` = `myschool_subject_section_classroom`.`subject_id` where `myschool_subject_section_classroom`.`classroom_id` = ? and `section_id` = ?"`
```

I can't figure what I am doing wrong here.
Please Help.

Comment: I know Laravel 4 did not support triple table pivots, hence e.g. this package (https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot) by @jarektkaczyk was created. Not sure if something similar exists for Laravel 5.

Comment: I think, that your tables structure is a little bit wrong. Can you give me some examples of sections and subjects from your tables, so I would better understand your logic.

Comment: actually i want to output all subjects of a classroom with its section. simple i wanted the classroom subjects from pivot table where section is as defined ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is coming from 
`php
$selected_subjects = $classroom->subjects()->where('section_id', '=', 1);`

Change it to:
`php
$selected_subjects = $classroom->subjects()->where('section_id', '=', 1)->get();`